# How can add VoIP development kit (v2dkTP) with my Qt SDK?

Tags: qt, sdk, installation, voip

I am working on a soft phone project. In this project I want to use the VoIP Development Kit. But I don't know how to add this library to my QtSDK. Anyone can help me in this issue?
To be specific I put that library in my SDK in different locations. But all the it gives the same error that VDKQtengine was declared with no type. What is the procedure to add this kit to my SDK? Do I have to call it in the project file? If so, then how could be it done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem by including INCLUDE PATH as the VDK directory.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm glad you found a solution to your issue. However, you need to ask a new question for your other issue. Also, as soon as you are able be sure and mark your answer as accepted so others will know that there is a solution.

Comment: Feel free to ask another question linking to this one for reference.